# android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, crash, onclicklistener

**Here is my adopter code for recyclerView**

**i even tried TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT but it's also giving the same result**
**When i'm trying to click the card view for recyclerView it's crashing all the time.**

```
class Adapter(data:ArrayList<CustomClass>, var context:Context):RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ViewHolder>() {

//constructor
var data:List<CustomClass>
init {
    this.data = data
}

override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
    val layout = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false)
    return ViewHolder(layout)
}

@RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    holder.name.text = data[position].name
    holder.image.setImageResource(data[position].image)
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener {
        val alert = Dialog(context)
        alert.setContentView(R.layout.alert)
        alert.window?.setType(WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST)

        val name = alert.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.alert_desc)
        val image = alert.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.alert_image)
        val spell = alert.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.alert_check)
        val done = alert.findViewById<Button>(R.id.alert_done)

        name.text = data[position].name
        image.setImageResource(data[position].image)

        alert.show()

        spell.setOnClickListener {
            holder.text2Speech = TextToSpeech(context, TextToSpeech.OnInitListener { status ->
                if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    holder.text2Speech.language = Locale.UK
                    holder.text2Speech.speak(data[position].name, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, null)
                }
            })
        }

        done.setOnClickListener {
            alert.dismiss()
        }

    }
}

override fun getItemCount(): Int {
    return data.size
}





class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    var name:TextView
    var image:ImageView
    var cardView:CardView
    lateinit var text2Speech:TextToSpeech

    init {
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_name)
        image = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_image)
        cardView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card)
    }

}
```

}

**And the error i'm getting**

2020-07-20 17:30:24.545 28603-28603/com.apurbamondal.androidspeechapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.apurbamondal.androidspeechapp, PID: 28603
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:840)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:356)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:94)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:329)
at com.apurbamondal.androidspeechapp.Adapter$onBindViewHolder$1.onClick(Adapter.kt:47)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)

Comment: use this ==> `val alert: Dialog = Dialog(context)`

Comment: give permission --> `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />`

Comment: same result...no improvement